# Make numbered headings in wordpress posts

Tags: html, wordpress, html-heading

When making "numbered list" item as 'heading 2', the h2 attributes are applied only to the text and the number before the text is still having the attributes of the paragraph tag as in the below picture,

[image]

Is there any way in wordpress to make the number even bold and have the attributes of heading tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for customize number style as examplate

```css
ol {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
  padding: 0;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol > li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 2em;
  text-indent: -2em;
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-increment: item;
  clear: borth;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
ol > li h1, ol > li h2, ol > li h3 {
  display: inline
}

ol > li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: right;
  content: counter(item) ".";
}
```

```html
<ol>
   <li><h1>The H1</h1></li>
   <li><h2>The H2</h2></li>
   <li><h3>The H3</h3></li>
</ol>
```